# How to do Insert/Update/Delete in single transaction in SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql

I should do Insert/Update/Delete with one transaction.
I have below data

```
DECLARE @EmpDetails TABLE(EmpID INT,TeamLeadID INT)
DECLARE @TeamManagement TABLE(TeamManagementID INT IDENTITY,TeamLeadID INT,EmpID INT)
```

Here one team lead can be assigned multiple Employees.
I need a Query/SP to do Insert/Update/Delete at a time in the below scenarios.

**1. Insert Scenario.**

When I pass TeamLeadID 213 and EmpID 123 the record is inserted as above as the TeamLead and EmpID combination is not there.

**2. Insert/Delete both**

When I pass TeamLeadID 213 and EmpID as '124,125', the records of 124 and 125 should be inserted and 123 should be deleted for that EmpID

**3. Delete the Record**

When I pass the EmpID as Null then the records with that EmpID to be deleted.

I am using the below code.

```
DECLARE @EMPID VARCHAR(100)='123,124'
DECLARE @TeamLeadID INT = 213
DECLARE @INSERT TABLE(EMPID INT)

SELECT value AS EmpID
FROM fnSplitText(@EMPID, ',');

INSERT INTO @TeamManagement(TeamLeadID,EmpID)
SELECT I.EmpID,@EmpID FROM @INSERT I
INNER JOIN @TeamManagement T ON I.EmpID = T.EmpID
WHERE TeamLeadID = @TeamLeadID
AND T.EmpID IS NULL;

DECLARE @Delete TABLE(EMPID INT)
DELETE T FROM @TeamManagement T
LEFT JOIN @INSERT I ON I.EmpID = T.EmpID
WHERE TeamLeadID = @TeamLeadID AND T.EmpID IS NULL;
```

Any other way to handle this to get the best performance/standards.I want this to be done without using MERGE.

Comment: Do you have any chance of managing some operations on your application side? It's very complicated. You only need an insert and delete sp.

Comment: I need to do it from Database side only.

Comment: There is no discernible difference in the data stored between `EmpDetails` and `TeamManagement` - why are these separate entitites?  I can't really provide you a good solution until that's resolved.

Comment: [`BEGIN TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`COMMIT TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/commit-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used to wrap multiple DML statements. Why is that unacceptable?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you may delete all records in TeamManagement table having your TeamLeadID.
Then insert rows that you sent.
No need to check anything.
This will solve NULL EmpId deleting and existing checking problems.

```
DECLARE @EMPID VARCHAR(100)='123,124';
DECLARE @TeamLeadID INT = 213;


DELETE FROM @TeamManagement
WHERE TeamLeadID = @TeamLeadID;


INSERT INTO @TeamManagement
SELECT @TeamLeadID, value AS EmpID
FROM fnSplitText(@EMPID, ',');
```

Comment: I am maintaining some triggers on Insert and Delete. So it unnecessarily having multiple triggers.

Comment: You may use enable-disable option.`DISABLE TRIGGER dbo.[TRG_Delete] ON dbName.dbo.TableName
GO

-- actions

ENABLE TRIGGER dbo.[TRG_Delete]  ON dbName.dbo.TableName
GO`

Comment: I want to do it using temp tables